# python: How to calculate the new date knowing the number of hours passed since a base date?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a base date and an amount of passed hours since that date and want to calculate the new date. Here is the code:

```
import datetime

date_time_str = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.0'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

passed_hour = 1047486
```

Can python achieve this automatically or I should do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use timedelta and add it to your existing datetime obj like this:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta

date_time_str = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.0'
date_time_obj = dt.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

passed_hour = 1047486

new_date_time_obj = date_time_obj + timedelta(hours=passed_hour)

print(new_date_time_obj)
```